# Type-abbreviation with compile-time check with zero overhead

Tags: performance, f#

Is it possible ? and does my little hack work ?

```
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit,Size=8)>]
type Slice = 
    struct
        [<FieldOffset(0)>]val mutable Address: int64
    end

let incSlice (slice: Slice) = slice.Address + 1L

let incInt64 (address: int64) = address + 1L
```

Are `incSlice` and `incInt64` compiled to the same assembly code ?

Timing nearly identical but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: This is not actually a type abbreviation.  That would be something like `type shortname = Some.Long.Path.That.You.Want.To.Abbreviate * That.might.even.be.a.Tuple`

Comment: Yes, just a hope that it will work like type-abbreviation (zero overhead) but safe (compile-time check)

Comment: Why not just use Units of measure - this is a perfect example - just do something like `[<Measure>] type Address` then `let slice (t:int64<Address>)= t+1L<Address>`

Comment: @JohnPalmer exactly what I want, thank you!!! Please make it an answer :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is trying to add compile time safety to a function without impacting the run-time performance.  While the struct with only a single field may work, it can be hard to predict.

Instead, a better solution is [Units of measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx)

You can define a measure type with

```
[<Measure>] type Address
```

then the function becomes

```
let slice (t:int64<Address>)= t+1L<Address>
```

The compiler will completely optimise away the measure type, while providing type safety.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with trivial benchmarks is that the optimiser always causes confusion. However I tried a simple test by building an exe in Release mode and looking at the disassembly in the debugger.

It looks like `Slice` does still have some more address calculation work than the `int64` version:

```
        let v1 = incSlice sl1
00000066  lea         edi,[ebp-1Ch] 
00000069  lea         esi,[ebp-14h] 
0000006c  movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [esi] 
00000070  movq        mmword ptr [edi],xmm0 
00000074  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch] 
00000077  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-18h] 
0000007a  mov         ecx,1 
0000007f  xor         ebx,ebx 
00000081  add         eax,ecx 
00000083  adc         edx,ebx 
00000085  mov         dword ptr [ebp-24h],eax 
00000088  mov         dword ptr [ebp-20h],edx 

        let v2 = incInt64 n
0000008b  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8] 
0000008e  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch] 
00000091  mov         ecx,1 
00000096  xor         ebx,ebx 
00000098  add         eax,ecx 
0000009a  adc         edx,ebx 
0000009c  mov         dword ptr [ebp-2Ch],eax 
0000009f  mov         dword ptr [ebp-28h],edx
```

In another test I worked directly with a literal value, and found that the `int64` version got optimised to the result whereas the `Slice` version didn't - i.e. its existence seems to defeat the optimiser in more cases.

**EDIT**: Note this is 32-bit. 64-bit generally looks nicer as per Viet NT's answer.

Also it turns out this only happens if you run the program under the debugger to begin with. If you attach the debugger after the methods have run then the code looks very similar and the variant with literal values gets constant folded for both the `int64` and `Slice` cases.

Comment: One difference between these is that I believe the first version is reporting an extra value if the addition overflows (through the `adc` instruction) - I believe that is the source of most of the difference.  Possibly since you have a literal in the second case it gets inlined and so the overflow check is optimised away.

Comment: That was part of my point - the optimiser noticed that I was using a literal in the `int64` case and optimised it, but didn't in the `Slice` case. However I've tweaked it to make sure that neither can see the literal any more; the code looks closer now but I think there's still more work going on in the former case.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Noticed that but I've read somewhere that disassembly in the debugger is not the optimized assembly JIT generated, is it ?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam can you share your tweak? or your case when int64 got optimized and Slice didn't ?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam did you turn off prefer 32bit ?

Comment: I was making 32-bit builds, yes. 64-bit looks much more like your code below. Also you're right about the debugger, I tried again only attaching after the code had run and everything went directly through registers.

Answer (score 1):

Seem very identical now

```
let test1(s: Slice) = 
    printfn "%d" 10
    let x = s.address + 1
    printfn "%d" x
```

produce

```
000000c1  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+000000A0h] 
000000c9  inc         rax 
000000cc  mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],rax
```

seem optimized

and with the help of inline

```
let inline incSlice(s: Slice) = s.address + 1

let test2 (s: Slice) =
    printfn "%d" 10
    let x = incSlice s
```

produce

```
000000be  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+000000A0h] 
000000c6  mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h],rax 
000000cb  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+30h] 
000000d0  inc         rax 
000000d3  mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],rax
```

Nearly identical with `test1`

Funny assembly code :D, `rax` moving around - the reason I don't think disassembly in the debugger is optimized